# Binding To A ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This has been asked before. I have tried several things and read a lot of posts but can't get this working. What happens is the window opens and I don't see columns in the `listview`. Instead I see `System.Windows.Controls.Gridview Columns=3`

The XAML and code-behind. I can post the `ViewModel` if necessary

<sup>**XAML**</sup>

```xml
<Window x:Class="DataBinding.LogFileWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBinding"
        Title="LogFileWindow" Height="556.183" Width="717.987">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>


                <TabPanel Margin="12,131,128.6,12.4" Width="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TabControl Margin="10,10,-270,-223.8">
                <TabItem Header="Logging Log">
                        <ListView Name="LoggingListView" ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}">
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date}"></GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Time}"></GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Event" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Event}"></GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Accounting Log">
                    <ListView Name="AccountingListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,-14.6,38.2"></ListView>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="NVRAM Log">
                    <ListView Name="NVRAMListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ListView>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </TabPanel>

    </Grid>
```

**<sup>C#</sup>**

```cs
     public MainWindow()
        {   
            //create a new logging log file
            LoggingLog logfile = new LoggingLog();

            //add some entries
            // these are not real dates and times but that doesn't matter much.


            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                LogFileEntry le = new LogFileEntry();
                le.Date = String.Format("Date{0}", i);
                le.Time = String.Format("Time{0}", i);
                le.Event = String.Format("Event{0}", i);
              logfile.LogEntryList.Add(le);
            }

            //now load the viewmodel

            LogViewModel logviewmodel = new LogViewModel();
            foreach (LogFileEntry le in logfile.LogEntryList)
            {
                logviewmodel.Add(new LogEntryViewModel(le));

            }

            //now set the datacontext on the window
            LogFileWindow lfwindow = new LogFileWindow();
            lfwindow.LogEntries = logviewmodel;
            lfwindow.LoggingListView.DataContext = logviewmodel;

            InitializeComponent();
            lfwindow.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XAML above inserts the GridView object as the content of the ListView.  So it overrides the ItemsSource.  you want to assign the GridView as the View of the ListView:

```
<ListView Name="LoggingListView" ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date}"></GridViewColumn>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Time}"></GridViewColumn>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Event" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Event}"></GridViewColumn>
         </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: ah crud.  Ok.  Now I see columns but the ListView is still empty.  Do you need to see the code-behind and/or the ViewModel?

Comment: I would suggest checking your output window and see if there are any databinding errors.  If you don't see anything in there, then you may want to use Snoop (great tool, if you don't have it already) to take a closer look at your ListView.  Unfortunately, I'm not in a place where I can do any more troubleshooting for the binding on the ListView right now.

Comment: I have a data binding error "property not found on object".  Thanks that at least is a start.