# More Binding To ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml

Original question was here.
[Binding To A ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150067/binding-to-a-listview)

I have fixed one issue and now see the column names. However, I can't figure out the binding.

The error from the output window:

```
 System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 
'ElementName=This'. BindingExpression:Path=LogView.LogEntries; DataItem=null; target 
element is 'ListView' (Name='LoggingListView'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type     'IEnumerable')
```

Snippet of the XAML with my latest attempt from LogFileWindow.XAML. I can post more but trying to keep the clutter down:

```
   <ListView Name="LoggingListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This,  Path=LogView.LogEntries}  ">
                        <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Time}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Event" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Event}"></GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

The C# ViewModel:

```
public class LogEntryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public LogEntryViewModel(LogFileEntry le)
    {
        _date = le.Date;
        _time = le.Time;
        _event = le.Event;
    }     
    #region Members
    private string _date;
    public string Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set {_date = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Date");           
        }
    }

    private string _time;
    public string Time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set
        {
            _time = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Time");

        }
    }

    private string _event;
    public string Event
    {
        get { return _event; }
        set { _event = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Event");
        }
    }
    private LogFileEntry _le;
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class LogViewModel :ObservableCollection<LogEntryViewModel>
{
       private ObservableCollection<LogEntryViewModel> _LogEntries;
    public ObservableCollection<LogEntryViewModel> LogEntries = new    
  ObservableCollection<LogEntryViewModel>();

}
```

Partial Class declaration and code-behind where I am trying to use it:

```
public partial class LogFileWindow : Window
{
    public  LogViewModel LogView = new LogViewModel();
```

}

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Why isn't the Binding working.  If it were working why would I be posting this asking for help?  Weren't "I got one part working" and "I can't figure out the binding" enough of a clue to figure out the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio error is pretty self-evident and self explanatory: you're trying to do Binding with ElementName and searching for a visual element (supposedly defined in your XAML visual tree) with Name="This". There's no such thing (apparently, I couldn't tell because you didn't post the complete XAML tree).

If you want to bind a Visual Element Property to another Property in the same element you have you use [RelativeSource Self](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.self.aspx)

Comment: thanks.  I thought "This" was the this keyword referring back to the window itself.